# Is using the word Roleplay with overseas minor can land me in jail

Tags: criminal-law, international, india, minor, sexual-offences

Hypothetical Question:
I am using an adult app (18+) for roleplaying. A girl from South Africa joined. She told her age is 14. I asked "wanna do roleplay?" She also kept her category in Roleplay. Then she said I'm underage you creep" and then closed the chat. We didn't say anything nor did we send any pictures.
Is it illegal? Will I be jailed over just saying "wanna do roleplay". I am 19 year old.

Is this chatting with a minor is illegal?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by roleplaying? It has a [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roleplay_%28disambiguation%29) of contexts - some appropriate for children and some not.

Comment: We didnt exchange any other words,so i think there is no other context. And it is an adult app strictly for 18...will i go to jail for this overseas?

Comment: Another question is it serious crime?....i heard overseas cybercrime is not prosecuted generally unless it is very serious,is it true!

Comment: what does the app mean by role playing? Or, what app is it?

Comment: What's your location? It's possible you might be covered under "Romeo and Juliet" laws.

Comment: It is Anon app,it is 18+ so probably roleplay does not mean good here,

Comment: How romeo and juliet law works here,no sexual words are exchanged.      M6 friend did this...he lives in india

Comment: So she said she was 14, and you invited her to join a chat of some sexual nature. That _could_ be trouble.

Comment: My friend went to a lawyear and he said that overseas cybercrime is not prosecuted unless it is too serious,he didnt exchange any photos neither forced to chat...it is an adult website..so is it e serious crime?and how will be this prosecuted overseas?

Comment: I am confused of the setup. I see at least two different setups... a) The app offering chat is for adults and to get access you must represent you are an adult. It is the understanding of the people there that all people are adults, but a minor snuck in. b) the app offers chat for everybody and you do not need to represent yourself an adult. There are chat groups of adult nature. You talk in one of them, and someone enters. They tell they are a minor when asked about the adult topic of the group.

Comment: The first setup is correct. You have to confirm that you are 18+ to chat. It is an app only for adult

Answer (score 2):

**Is this chatting with a minor is illegal?**

Possibly, as a hypothetical<sup>1</sup>, under [section 67](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_45_76_00001_200021_1517807324077&orderno=83), Information Technology Act 2000:

> Whoever publishes or **transmits** or causes to be published or transmitted in the electronic form, any material which is lascivious or appeals to the prurient interest or if its effect is such as **to tend to deprave and corrupt persons** who are likely, having regard to all relevant circumstances, to read, see or hear the matter contained or embodied in it, shall be punished on first conviction with imprisonment of either description for a term which may extend to three years and with fine which may extend to five lakh rupees and in the event of second or subsequent conviction with imprisonment of either description for a term which may extend to five years and also with fine which may extend to ten lakh rupees.

Whether the question "***wanna do roleplay***?" is enough - on its own - to demonstrate an offence has been committed will depend on the court...

> ...having regard to all relevant circumstances...

<sup>1</sup>But if all that was said and done is as per the OP, it's highly unlikely this would go anywhere near the court in real life, especially as [de minimis non curat lex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/de+minimis+non+curat+lex).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My friends got relieved. Yeah this is the only conversation they had. They didnot exchange any words more than this.